# Make feature layer managment

Tags: arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute

I have a feature class that includes 49 points (records). I want to select specified FID that I've mentioned before for example `my_fid = (0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,12,45)`. so I want to select this fid with ArcPy and using the Make Feature Class. How can I define a variable to use IN operator for where clause.

Comment: My_fid IN (0,1,2......45)

Comment: sql_exp = "FID IN {0}".format(str(my_fid))

Comment: @Clubdebambos thanks a lot you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use AddFieldDelimiters and format:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb'
feature_class = 'ak_riks'
field_to_select_by = 'OBJECTID'

sql = "{0} IN (132, 254)".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=feature_class, field=field_to_select_by))

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=feature_class, out_layer='selected', where_clause=sql)

#If you want to create a new feature class
arcpy.SelectData_management(in_dataelement=feature_class, out_dataelement='ak_riks_subset')
```